# How to store JSON object as option value in select tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append JSON object to a select tag for future reference by using below code

```
          $.each(actualData, function (key, value) {

                                      var valueToAppend = [];
                                      var vehicleId = value._id['$oid'];
                                      var availableSeats = value.NumberOfSeats;

                                      var item = {};
                                          item["VehicleId"] = vehicleId;
                                          item["AvailableSeats"] = availableSeats;

                                          valueToAppend.push(item);
       $('#vehicle_'+guid).append($('<option>', {value: '' + valueToAppend + '', text: '' + value.VehicleNumber + ''}));
                });
```

It is appending values in browser like  "value="[object Object]".

I want it should append like {VehicleId:"36ae8c855677879c88", AvailableSeats: "60"}. I want it should store id and number of seats. Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store an object as a value of HTML element. So you have to  store json string as a value

```
 $('#vehicle_'+guid).append($('<option>', {value: '{VehicleId:' + valueToAppend.item.VehicleId+',AvailableSeats:'+valueToAppend.item.AvailableSeats+ '}', text:value.VehicleNumber}));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this . I am converting your Object to JSON String

```
$('#vehicle_'+guid)
         .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",JSON.stringify(valueToAppend))
                    .text(value.VehicleNumber));
```